# Verbosity in boost asio using ssl

Tags: c++, ssl, boost-asio, verbosity

Is there a way to make ssl handshake more visible to me using boost asio?
I am getting an error: "asio.ssl error". 
I just want more verbosity, because this message means almost nothing to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that boost.asio with ssl use openssl.

I just need to recompile the libssl with debug flags to make ssl handshake process more verbose. I can do this just reconfiguring with './config -DKSSL_DEBUG'.

In the boost documentation I found no way to control the verbosity level.