# Boost error codes human-readable description

Tags: c++, boost, error-handling, boost-asio

I'm catching errors in Boost Asio program like

```
if (!error)
{
    //do stuff
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Error : " << error << std::endl;
    //handle error
}
```

But the error isn't human-readable (e.g. connecting to SSL server without certificate gives error asio.ssl:335544539). Is there any better way how to display error ?

Comment: What type is error? What is function is populating the error field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decipher a boost asio ssl error code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828066/how-to-decipher-a-boost-asio-ssl-error-code)

Comment: Try this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448715/verbosity-in-boost-asio-using-ssl

Comment: Note that if you intend to display such errors to your users, you probably should do it in a way it can be localized.

Comment: @JonCage: I disagree about the "duplicate", those questions asked how to work around the issue or provide more logs, but not how to get human-friendly messages.

Comment: @Matthieu: That's not what 'Is there any better way how to display error' sounded like to me - I thought he wanted to know what the error meant. Happy to accept I misinterpreted the OPs question though..

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you are likely using `boost::system::error_code` you can call:

```
error.message()
```

to get a more human-friendly message.

Using `operator<<` translates into:

```
os << ec.category().name() << ':' << ec.value()
```

[Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/system/doc/reference.html#Class-error_code) you can check a detailed overview of the available members in `error_code`.